# why do all digits of an ipv6 address get separated in an spf `{ir}` macro?

Tags: spf

The last example at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7208#section-7.4 shows the expansion of the spf macro `%{ir}.%{v}._spf.%{d2}` with values sender: `strong-bad@email.example.com`, Pv6 SMTP client IP is `2001:db8::cb01` and The PTR domain name of the client IP as `mx.example.org` as `1.0.b.c.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.b.d.0.1.0.0.2.ip6._spf.example.com`, and I don't understand why the digets of the ipv6 address all end up separated. I expected the `{ir}` pattern to produce either `2001:db8::cb01` or `2001:db8:00000:00000:0000:cb01`

Why does it get expanded as shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i` macro expands to the dot-format representation used for example in reverse DNS queries:

```
$ host 2607:f8b0:4864:20::e34
4.3.e.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.2.0.0.4.6.8.4.0.b.8.f.7.0.6.2.ip6.arpa domain name pointer mail-vs1-xe34.google.com.
```

The dot format representation is suitable for the recursive SPF lookups as used in SPF records.

Use the `c` macro to get the pretty printed format instead. The pretty format is not suitable for DNS queries so it is available only in SPF explain strings.

Comment: What exactly is the dot format representation? It's not in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4291#section-2.2

Comment: @Martijn It is an encoding of IP addresses as domain names. This is the format used in PTR lookups. In SPF, this could be used for example with the *exists* mechanism for fine-grained access control (though I have never actually seen this). I don’t know which DNS RFC to point you to.